# Audio overlap issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing a iOS app using objective-c. When the application is launched a background music is played. The background music should continue playing when the user clicks help button. Also when the user goes back to the main screen from the help screen the background music should be continuously playing.

For me a new background music is getting played along with the old background music when I navigate from help to main menu. So, I am hearing two background music now.

Could anyone help me in solving this issue?

Regards,
Bharathi.

Comment: It sounds like you are not stopping the old background player, but creating a new one when returning to the main screen.  But with no code to debug or see what you are currently doing we can't help you in the slightest...  Sorry.

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
 
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"music.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
    NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];                                                 [_audioPlayer play];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be solved if you retained a reference to your audio player in your UIApplicationDelegate (or some other singleton that's kept around).

```
//in the .h
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *player;

//in the .m

- (void) playMusic
{
    if (self.player == nil) {
        NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/music.mp3", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]];
        NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    }
    if (!self.player.isPlaying) {
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

That way you can call it wherever you need with a:

```
[(MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate playMusic];
```

Though it might be to your advantage to keep around a SoundsManager class as a singleton in order to handle all the sounds that you'll need to track if you're going to need more than just this one.